# How do I get Pillow ImageOps.contain to work when inside VS Code?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have VS Code on a Mac.
Pillow is installed and version verified as 8.3.2 via Pip list in the terminal window of VS Code.  I have confirmed via the pillow docs that the [ImageOps.contain()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.contain) is part of 8.3.

My problem is that when I use the terminal, type python and run the following, it works perfectly:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

im = Image.open("images/Barcelona.jpg")

print(im.format, im.size, im.mode)
im = ImageOps.contain(im, (800, 800), method=3)

im.show()
```

[image: my terminal window]

Preview pops right up and shows me the picture.

When I put the exact code into VS Code or build a .py file with Nano, I get an error message which is shown in this image:

[image: the error message from running in VS Code.]

I've verified the right version of Python, Pillow, and such.  Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the output of  `from PIL import __version__` `print(__version__)` in both cases?

Comment: I get 8.2.0 when I put that in the VS Code block.   I get an error when trying to do it the case of doing it one line at a time at the >>> prompt.  However, I believe I have found the conflict with respect anaconda and what env I'm in.  Checking that now.  The import version variable was not something I knew. I do now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a problem with what I can only call nested environments and/or a conflict between Anaconda and Workspaces.  I'm not really sure but when I used the _version import to figure out a) what VS Code thought and then b) figured out the environment Pip was reporting on, I deactivated up one level, upgraded the (base) to the 8.3 version and all ran fine.  The knowledge on importing the version variable to see precisely what the code is importing came from the question asked below and was invaluable.